# Calculating edge embeddedness for signed graph in R

Tags: r, graph

I have a dataframe looks like

`src dst sign
0 1 +1
1 2 -1
2 5 +1
1 0 -1
...`

to describe a signed graph (with two types of edges: +/-)

I want to calculate [edge embeddedness](https://networksandcities.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/embeddedness-and-neighborhood-overlap/) of this graph.

Currently, I am writing two nested loop (i.e., a brute-force attack: just count one by one).

You could imagine that this solution is very slow.

Is there a better way to perform the task?

Thank you very much,

Comment: I guess, drawing a histrogram is not the problem. In this case your question would be how to efficently calculate edge embeddedness, right? I'm not experienced with this package, but `igraph` could be promising (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html).

Comment: yes, histogram is not a problem.

Comment: Hello, I checked [igraph documentation](http://igraph.org/r/doc/) but did not find anything related to edge embeddedness?

Comment: In https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/news.html embeddings are mentioned. But I don't know if this can help you - it's just an idea. Regarding your question, I would suggest that you drop the unnecessary part about the histogram. This would improve your question as the histrogram distracts from your actual question.

Comment: yeah, I removed the question part about histogram